# PHP age verification that works with links instead of form buttons for crawling

Tags: php, forms, session

I'm developing a website that needs age verification. If someone access the website has to be redirected to the age verification page, regardless of the URL that types in. In an ideal world this age verification page would be different to index.php, something like /verification or similar.

I know that the crawlers have issues passing this verification when form buttons are used, so what I need is a script that works with 2 links: I'm over 18 and I'm under 18. These 2 links will be images linking to the main homepage of the website or to somewhere else in the net.

Most of the age verification scripts use a date of birth picker, but after a bit of research I've stumbled upon this code posted in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965731/age-verification-help-to-explanation-the-script):

```
<?php
session_start();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if (isset($_POST['YES'])) {
        $redirect = isset($_GET['return']) ? urldecode($_GET['return']) : './';
        $expire = isset($_GET['x']) && is_numeric($_GET['x']) ? intval($_GET['x']) : -1;
        if ($expire == - 1) {
            $_SESSION['verified'] = "yes";
            header("location: " . $redirect);
            exit(0);
        }

        if ($expire == 0) {
            setcookie("verified", "yes", mktime(0, 0, 0, 01, 01, date("Y") + 30));
            $_SESSION['verified'] = "yes";
            header("location: " . $redirect);
            exit(0);
        }

        setcookie("verified", "yes", (time() + $expire));
        $_SESSION['verified'] = "yes";
        header("location: " . $redirect);
        exit(0);
    }
    else {
        header("location: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gppbrYIcR80");
        exit(0);
    }
}

?>
```

```
function verified(){
    $redirect_url = 'http://www.YOURSITEROOT.com/verify.php';
    $expires = - 1;
    session_start();
    $validated = false;

    if (!empty($_COOKIE["verified"])) {
        $validated = true;
    }

    if (!$validated && isset($_SESSION['verified'])) {
        $validated = true;
    }

    if (is_numeric($expires) && $expires == - 1 && !isset($_SESSION['verified'])) {
        $validated = false;
    }

    if ($validated) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        $redirect_url = $redirect_url . "?return=" . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . "&x=" . $expires;
        Header('Location: ' . $redirect_url);
        exit(0);
    }
}

verified();
?>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>
      Alcohol Age Verification Example Page
      </title>
      <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <form action="" method="POST">
          <p id="textVerify">
            PLEASE VERIFY THAT YOU ARE OVER AGE 21 BEFORE ENTERING THIS SITE
          </p>
          <input name="NO" id="no" type="Submit" value="NO - Leave" />
          <input name="YES" id="yes" type="Submit" value="Yes - Enter" />
        </form>
      </body>
</html>
```

Can someone help me to make it work with images+links instead of the submit buttons and redirecting to mydomain.com/verification instead of mydomain.com/index.php to vertify the age? Would I need to use any .htaccess rules besides the script?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: way too complicated. Just put up an image like this: http://cheezburger.com/4774559488

Comment: how old is a crawler bot ?

Comment: @Dagon do you count it from page views or what? /sarcasm.

Comment: I'd start counting when it reaches beta.

Comment: @SLaRe instead of copying and pasting an entire code from another question, **try making** some code that shows an image and accepts the answer then post an specific question of what is not working for you with it. And no, you don't need .htacces just PHP and Sessions is enough, if session does not have a valid age verification send it to the verification page.

Comment: Thank you Prix for your reply. The thing is that I'm not 100% sure on how to change the code from submit buttons to links.